# How to send a broadcast beacon wirelessly in omnetpp using the Inet framework?

Tags: c++, simulation, omnet++, inet

I want the node start broadcast a beacon when the simulation start and when it recieve one it reply whith recieved , I'm new to omnetpp i inspired the Schema of the code from Aodv  ,please help me
I'm using  OMNET++ 6.0.1 and INET Framework 4.4.1

I created a Node that extends from AdhocHost :

```
package inet.node.localisation;
import inet.node.inet.AdhocHost;
import inet.routing.localisation.Localisation;

 module LocalisationNode extends AdhocHost
 {
    submodules:
        localisation: Localisation {
            @display("p=825,226");
        }
    connections:
        localisation.socketOut --> at.in++;
        localisation.socketIn <-- at.out++;
}
```

this is the Localisation.h :

```
#ifndef __INET_LOCALISATION_H
#define __INET_LOCALISATION_H

namespace omnetpp{
namespace inet {

class  Localisation : public cSimpleModule{
protected:
  virtual void initialize(int stage) override;
  virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg) override;

public:
  Localisation();
    virtual ~Localisation();
};

} /* namespace inet */
}
#endif /* INET_MYPROTOCOL_MYPROTOCOL_H_ */
```

This is the Localisation.cc :

```
#include "inet/routing/localisation/Localisation.h"


namespace omnetpp{
namespace inet {

Define_Module(Localisation);
void Localisation::initialize(int stage)
{
 
}

void Localisation::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
 
}

Localisation::Localisation() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}

Localisation::~Localisation() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}

} }/* namespace inet */
```

And the Localisation.ned :

```
package inet.routing.localisation;
import inet.applications.contract.IApp;
    module Localisation like IApp
    {
        @class("Localisation");
        @display("i=block/network2");
        gates:
        input socketIn;
        output socketOut;
    }
```

Comment: What's actually wrong with your code?

Comment: i want to broadcast a message using wifi i don't know how